# Extra slash on email subject

Tags: php, email, sendmail

I use this sample of code to send email from php

```
<?php
$to      = 'nobody@example.com';
$subject = $_POST['subject']; //"the \test subject's";
$message = $_POST['body']; //'hello';
$headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```

but when i recieve the email the subject displayed like that

```
the \\test subject's
```

How to remove this extra slash ?

Thanks

Comment: Change the `$subject` variable's quotes to single quotes... not quite sure why you've got a slash in the subject, though...

Comment: @BigChris i tried it also. Some customer may send me an email (contact us) and he insert a backslash into the subject

Comment: is that exact code running and having the additional \? or is there some $_POST / $_GET in the code that you're not showing here. I think there is something missing what you're showing here is something that couldn't happen...

Comment: @CodeBird it just a sample not exact code. And yes i use $_POST to get the values of the form ... now  can edit the question

Comment: Do you have magic quotes enabled? That could explain this issue.

Comment: you have magic quotes turned on, which should be off... http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php. if you can't turn it off just `stripslashes` from `$_POST` before doing anything with it

Comment: @Ja͢ck magic quotes is enabled.

Comment: @CodeBird sorry it's already off ... and i tried to use stripslashes on $_POST but it remove the backslash ever. i just want it to remove the extra slash only to be like that -> the \test subject's

Comment: Am using PHP version 5.4

Comment: can we see the exact code you're using...

Comment: @CodeBird my code more complicated that this ... but i believe that the $_POST['subject'] at that line just before calling mail() has only one backslash

Comment: what do you see if you `echo $subject;` before mail()? and why did you tell me magic quotes is off and you told Ja͢ck that it is enabled? which one is true?

Comment: i see that -> the est subject's but i think that because of browser.

Comment: the magic quotes is off .. tried to edit the comment for Jack but it doesn't save

Answer (score 0):

From http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php :

> subject 
>   Subject of the email to be sent.
>
> Caution Subject must satisfy » RFC 2047.

RFC 2047 : http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2047.html

Wish it will help you.